# Связь таблицы с excel

Tags: delphi-7, delphi, excel

вот готовый код с таблицей и мне надо переместить эту таблицу в excel я не знаю как помгите мне пожайлуста.:))

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var

 i,result:integer;//объявление переменных

w:array[0..9,0..2] of integer;

begin

 begin

   writeln('V=V0-a*t from it we have V0=V-a*t');

   writeln('write here 10 value of V and then click to enter');

   for i:= 0 to 9 do

   readln(w[i,0]);//чтобы прочитать переменную заданную пользователем

   writeln('write here 10 value of a and then click to enter');

   for i:= 0 to 9 do

   readln(w[i,1]);

   writeln('write here 10 value of t and then click to enter');

   for i:= 0 to 9 do

   readln(w[i,2]);

   for i:= 0 to 9 do

   Writeln('RESULT:', w[i,0]-w[i,1]*w[i,2]);//для вывода результата

 readln;//для вывода результата

   readln;//чтобы преложение не "вылетало"

 end;

writeln(' ');

 for i:= 0 to 9 do

 begin

   write('V=',w[i,0],'     a=',w[i,1],'     t=',w[i,2],'    V0=', w[i,0]-w[i,1]*w[i,2]);

   writeln(' ')

  end;

readln;

end.
```

Comment: @КУдак, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@КУдак](/users/16599/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA), тут не принято просить сделать работу за вас.Так что придется самостоятельно разобраться, потом приходите с конкретными вопросами.

Список литературы для ознакомления:

- [Excel ЧаВо часть I: Excel.Application](http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1270)
- [Excel ЧаВо часть II: Worksbooks и Worksheets](http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1273)
- [Excel ЧаВо часть III: Cells, Range, Rows и Columns](http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1274)
- [Excel ЧаВо часть IV: Chart, Shape, Picture](http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1275)
- [Excel ЧаВо часть V: Внешние источники данных](http://delphikingdom.ru/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=1277)